# jquery find doesn't select desired div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```js
$('article').addClass('new-article');
$($('.new-article').find('div')[1]).addClass('new-row');
```

```css
.row {
  color: red;
}
.new-row {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>

  <div class="row">text text 1</div>
  <div class="row">text text 2</div>
  <div class="row">text text 3</div>
  <div class="row">text text 4</div>
  <div class="row">text text 5</div>
  <div class="row">text text 6</div>
  <div class="row">text text 7</div>
  <div class="row">text text 8</div>

</article>
```

What I want to achieve is that to add that custom class on second div and apply custom css, and also to add this on fourth div as well.
I only need it on second and fourth div.

I know that I didn't add in jsfiddle part of the code for that fourth div, but logic should be the same...

Any ideas?

**EDIT :**
I changed that custom to new and updated link, sorry about this.

Problem is that I only want to have blue text in second div and fourth div and not in all divs.

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/mh4b741w/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery function `filter` to target just 2nd and 4th `div`s :

```
$('article').addClass('new-article');

$('.new-article div').filter(function( index ){
     return index == 1 || index == 3;
}).addClass('new-row');
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('article').addClass('new-article');

$('.new-article div').filter(function( index ){
     return index == 1 || index == 3;
}).addClass('new-row');
```

```css
.row{
    color:red;  
}

.new-row{
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>

        <div class="row">text text 1</div>
        <div class="row">text text 2</div>
        <div class="row">text text 3</div>
        <div class="row">text text 4</div>
        <div class="row">text text 5</div>
        <div class="row">text text 6</div>
        <div class="row">text text 7</div>
        <div class="row">text text 8</div>

</article>
```

Comment: I don't see how is this different to my updated link. Also how to target 4th as well? so only 2nd and 4th have blue color and the rest red? Thanks.

Comment: +1 but i would write `$('.new-article').find('div:eq(1)').addClass('new-row');` instead of `$($('.new-article').find('div')[1]).addClass('new-row');`

Comment: Thanks @MarcoMagrini for you vote and comment check my updated answer using filter().

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure that the DOM is actually ready when fetching by index.
Secoundary the use of `.eq()` gets everything easier, so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "div:eq(1)" ).addClass( "new-row" );
  $( "div:eq(3)" ).addClass( "new-row" );
});
```

put the script in the `<head>` of the document.

http://jsfiddle.net/mh4b741w/9/